# "ERROR: multiple values encountered for non multiValued field id_length: [7, 7]" but the original input does not have more than one value

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I'm using SolrJ to populate a collection in a solr cluster. In my the schema.xml the field `id_length` is defined as:

```
<field name="id_length" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

I'm populating the collection by batches of 1000, I'm trying to store 450k documents:

```
    public void write(SolrDocumentList page) throws SolrServerException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<SolrInputDocument> toIndex = new LinkedList<>();

        Iterator<SolrDocument> pageIt = page.iterator();

        while (pageIt.hasNext()) {
            SolrDocument resultDoc = pageIt.next();
            SolrInputDocument inputDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

            for (String name : resultDoc.getFieldNames()) {
                inputDoc.addField(name, resultDoc.getFieldValue(name));
            }

            toIndex.add(inputDoc);
        }

        client.add(context.stringParams.get("targetCollection"), toIndex);
        client.commit(context.stringParams.get("targetCollection"));

    }
```

But after some batches, it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_example_shard1_replica_n1: ERROR: [doc=b000001] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field id_length: [7, 7]
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:125)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.getRouteException(CloudSolrClient.java:46)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.directUpdate(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:579)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.sendRequest(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:1076)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:934)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseCloudSolrClient.request(BaseCloudSolrClient.java:866)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:71)
```

Here, the strange is that the input document where it crashes is the following:

```
SolrInputDocument(fields: [id=b000001, keyword=N/A, table=diagcodes, id_length=7])
```

Obviously, `id_length` does not have more than one value, so what happened????

I'm expecting that the script runs successfully with each batch, none of the documents has multivalue inputs.

Comment: Do you have any update processors attached to the request handler? What is the type of the field? (i.e. since it's a length field - are you using something that calculates the length for you, so you're including a value - and a value gets calculated - effectively giving two values?)

Comment: Do you have any copyField declarations in your schema?